# How to retrieve Request data form POST method form in a template of wordpress plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress, forms, post

I have developed a WordPress plugin, created a template in optin-template.php in plugin folder. Also the main plugin file optin.php is also at the same location.

I am using a form at this template page, and this template is loaded by the plugin.

My question is that, how can I get the `$_POST` data in "optin.php"?

I have created a page on frontend by name `/optin_country` which shows fine and working correct. This page has a form and I have to submit its data and catch it on optin.php.

I have tried both admin-post.php and admin-ajax.php but still not successful.

here is my code which i use to schedule the event which is working fine in optin.php but I have to use them in optin-template.php

```
f (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// 1. checking for email should not be bounced
$valid = optin_zerobounc($email);
//p_rr($valid,1);
$valid_email_status = $valid['status'];
// preparation for inserting into the central DB
    $body = array(
        'first_name' => $full_name,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'last_name' => $full_name,
        'country_code' => $country_code,
        'domain' => $domain
    );

    if($valid_email_status == 'valid'){

        // add data to f24sms API if email is validated
        $response = add_to_f24sms_api($body,'optin');
        //add data to Mailwhizz List
        $responsemw = mailwhizzApi($email,$full_name);

        //arguments to pass to the crons its an array with 2 values
        $args = array($email,$phone);
        print_r($args);
       // wp_schedule_single_event(time()+ MINUTE_IN_SECONDS ,'sms_cron_15min','123');
//        wp_schedule_single_event(time()+ 2 * HOUR_IN_SECONDS,'sms_cron_2hour',$args);
//        wp_schedule_single_event(time()+ 1 * DAY_IN_SECONDS,'sms_cron_1day',$args);
//        wp_schedule_single_event(time()+ 2 * DAY_IN_SECONDS,'sms_cron_2day',$args);
//        wp_schedule_single_event(time()+ 3 * DAY_IN_SECONDS,'sms_cron_3day',$args);
//        wp_schedule_single_event(time()+ 5 * DAY_IN_SECONDS,'sms_cron_5day',$args);
```

Comment: Please share your code from optin.php and optin-template.php with us

Comment: where are they?

Comment: If your template is indeed being loaded properly, then there is no reason why simply using the `$_POST` superglobal variable will not work if you are posting data to the same template.  `if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) { // do something with $_POST['variable'] }`

Comment: OP added the code files in a new answer below

Comment: actually i need to schedule an event with wp_schedule_single_event() which is working fine in optin.php but there I don't have $_POST data available in optin.php ,Or
Tell me how to pass these $_POST['email'] and $_POST['phone '] to plugin file ,,